# 301 Redirecting all articles from a old folder to a new folder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I need your help regarding redirect rules.

I have an old URL structure:

```
www.example.com/en/news/news/single/article/SPECIFIC-ARTICLE/
```

(with SPECIFIC-ARTICLE being a placeholder for a whole bunch of articles - with a trailing slash!).

After the relaunch the name and structure of the folders will change to:

```
www.example.com/en/news/SPECIFIC-ARTICLE
```

So all articles (with trailing) in the old structure should be redirected to the corresponding articles in the new structure. And shouldn't have a trailing slash anymore.

**How should the mod_rewrite rule in `.htaccess` look like?
And how would this rule change if there wasn't a trailing slash but a `.html` at the end of the old article URLs?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess` this would be something like (near the top of the file):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(en/news)/news/single/article/([\w-]+)/$ /$1/$2 [R=302,L]
```

`$1` is a backreference to the `en/news` match in the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (this is simply to avoid repetition). `$2` is a backreference to the *SPECIFIC-ARTICLE* (which is assumed to consist of just the letters `A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`, `_` and `-`).

If there is `.html` instead of the trailing slash, then change the `RewriteRule` *pattern* to:

```
RewriteRule ^(en/news)/news/single/article/([\w-]+)\.html$ /$1/$2 [R=302,L]
```

Note the dot is backslash escaped to match a literal dot and not *any character*.

Note that this is a temporary (302) redirect, change this to a 301 (permanent) redirect only when you are sure it is working OK.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick feedback. Why should I place the rule at the top of the file? I would have placed it at the end of the file after the redirects that I matched 1 to 1 with indidivual rewrite rules from the old domain to the new domain.

Comment: Ok, yes... it should come after any _specific_ 1 to 1 redirects. But it should go before any other rewrites (eg. front controller) etc.

Comment: (Basically, it should not go at the end of the file - which is what we're trying to avoid - but surprising, many people do this! Since you've not included any code in your question, it's not clear exactly where it should go - but _generally_, it should go near the top.)

Comment: Thanks for your useful input. Do you have any good literature / source in which all those .htaccess rules are explained?

Comment: You're welcome. The [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/) are my goto for [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/) etc. - although not everyone seems to get on with it and examples are a bit thin. Much of these directives get their power from [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) which is really another topic. Best of luck.